# Exposing multiple docker containers running locally

Tags: docker, nginx, web, ngrok, localtunnel

I am creating a SaaS project that lets end-users run and access a dashboard as a web app which is a Docker container, which means every user has his own dashboard which is a running docker container, and I would like them to access their servers/containers using my domain (HTTP) as follow: user1: subdomain.mydomain.com/user1app, user2: subdomain.mydomain.com/user1app, etc.

Currently, I am using LocalTunnel however it is not stable and requires me to use 1 subdomain for every user, for example: user1.mydomain.com, user2.mydomain.com, etc.
but what if we scale and get more users? I need a dynamic and automatic way to create users custom URL link to expose their running docker containers and give them access such as, subdomain.mydomain.com/user123, subdomain.mydomain.com/user456, etc.

I tried to use ngrok, however, it is limited in many ways e.g. 40-requests/minute limit, and not free.
Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, the 40 connections/min limit only applies to free ngrok accounts. Paid accounts do have higher limits.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running an nginx-revsere-proxy with docker and the you can host as many webapp as you want only with one single ip.

https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy

There you can add per host configs or even change the default configuration. So you can write for each dashboard a config or use variables and a bashscript to create the host configs

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would like to make it dynamically configured, plus some servers are running locally and I would like to expose them through tunneling.

Comment: Yeah, the this reverse proxy is looking for new container and then set up all automatically. Everything is controlled via environnement variables and there you also could set it, that it‘s only internaly reachable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple docker containers running locally, you can expose them to the internet using ngrok.

First, install ngrok:

$ npm install -g ngrok

Then, start ngrok and specify the port that your docker container is running on:

$ ngrok http 80

Ngrok will give you a URL that you can use to access your docker container from the internet.